# Get notified of up/down votes after 200 daily limit is reached

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit, achievements-dialog

I recently hit the max daily rep (200) for providing an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337238/63734) on the English Stack Exchange site.

Even though I am a person of great modesty and humbleness, **cough-cough**, I feel that it would be nice to know when my answer receives an upvote.

Is this possible?

Is this already occurring and I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Do you really need notifications about things that don't change you reputation at all? You can always see upvotes/downvotes on your profile reputation tab.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a need but I was just hoping to get other people's thoughts or links to other discussions on this topic.

Comment: I think this is one of those "it would be nice" things. I don't rep cap often but a lot of the time I don't even notice that I rep capped because the notifications stop coming in and it isn't until later in the day when UTC switches to a new day and I start getting rep again I realize that the answer is +30 or something but I'd assumed it was lower because I stopped getting notifications.

Comment: @Oded it's a positive change, regardless of the reputation. Same as being notified of badges, for example.

Answer (score 5):

You are not notified of this via the Achievements inbox, but you can still see the up- & downvotes on the [Reputation tab](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/63734/monkeyzeus?tab=reputation) in your Profile. They will appear in the list, but without the usual pluses or minuses.

[image]